What is the Roman Catholic position on ex-Roman Catholics who have later been "saved" in an evangelical sense?

As in the case of Baptism and Confirmation this share in Christ's office is granted once for all. the sacrament of Holy Orders, like the other two, confers an indelible spiritual character and cannot be repeated or conferred temporarily (Catechism of the Catholic Church, 1582)

A 1954 Time magazine article citing Rev. Daniel A. Poling estimated that, in the decade prior, as many as 4 million Catholics converted to Protestantism.  This is from a 2015 Pew research article on "faith switching":

One-in-five people who were raised Catholic now say they have no religious affiliation, while 10% identify with evangelical denominations, 5% with mainline denominations and smaller numbers with other faiths.

My question is: What is the Catholic view of those very many (multiple millions) of Baptized and Confirmed Roman Catholics who have later (in adult life) had the experience of being saved in the evangelical sense?

Definition:  Evangelicals believe that salvation is a personal and transformative experience that involves a "born-again" encounter with Jesus Christ. This experience is considered a passage from spiritual death to spiritual life.  It encompasses all the abiding and immediate effects (albeit some of the language is different) that are supposed to have been conferred in Catholic Baptism and Confirmation, especially the immediate results (copied from this question), such as:
Abiding Effects
Baptism: Incorporates us into Christ and his Church
Baptism: Capacity to receive other sacraments
Baptism: God's life, the life of the Holy Spirit
Confirmation: Configuration to Christ's priesthood
Confirmation: seals our souls like armor so that we can be knights in combat for Christ

Immediate Results
Baptism: Forgiveness of sin
Baptism: Bestowal of Sanctifying Grace
Baptism: Infusion of the Supernatural Virtues
Baptism: Infusion of the Gifts of the Holy Spirit
Baptism: Conferral of Actual Graces
Confirmation: Grace of mature, Christian witness
Confirmation: Grace of spiritual soldiery


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I don't think the numbers have any significance in the church's position.
As far as I can find there also is no specific position on what people exactly do or believe once they leave the church.
If, and that is a big if, someone is catholic and educated enough to know what the church teaches, this quote from Lumen Gentium, paragraph 14 comes to mind:

All the Church's children should remember that their exalted status is to be attributed not to their own merits but to the special grace of Christ. If they fail moreover to respond to that grace in thought, word and deed, not only shall they not be saved but they will be the more severely judged.
https://www.vatican.va/archive/hist_councils/ii_vatican_council/documents/vat-ii_const_19641121_lumen-gentium_en.html

Also I would point out what the catechism says in paragraph 846:

"Outside the Church there is no salvation"
How are we to understand this affirmation, often repeated by the Church Fathers? Re-formulated positively, it means that all salvation comes from Christ the Head through the Church which is his Body:
Basing itself on Scripture and Tradition, the Council teaches that the Church, a pilgrim now on earth, is necessary for salvation: the one Christ is the mediator and the way of salvation; he is present to us in his body which is the Church. He himself explicitly asserted the necessity of faith and Baptism, and thereby affirmed at the same time the necessity of the Church which men enter through Baptism as through a door. Hence they could not be saved who, knowing that the Catholic Church was founded as necessary by God through Christ, would refuse either to enter it or to remain in it.

(Italics added by me)
I could quote quite a lot other official documents but the general message is always something like this: if you don't know any better, that is not your fault, but if you know better, and actively leave the church (being the Roman Catholic Church), salvation becomes problematic.

So, those many multiple millions who now pursue and experience a vibrant and living relationship with God the Father through Christ are likely lost unless they return to the religious system wherein they did not have such a relationship?

@MikeBorden  I think "where they did not have such a relationship" might actually be "where they did not feel such a relationship."

@AndreasBlass Even if that is granted, aren't those people being asked/required to go back to where they didn't feel anything?

Who said belief is about feeling something?

I see the intellect and the will (faith, love) as the essential part of religion. Emotions are at best secondary. Of course it's a great blessing if one's emotions support the intellect and will, but that blessing has sometimes been denied even to great saints.

Mike Borden, I answered a question about the position of the Catholic Church. Your question is a matter of belief, I could give you my belief, but what would that really do for you?

@MikeBorden Imagining myself to be a cradle Catholic later confirmed through the normal process during teen years (which I'm not), if I'm later becoming more aware of the significance of Jesus through Evangelical Protestant preaching, my response would be to receive the Catholic Eucharist bread with a lot more appreciation and in deeper faith. Every sacrament becomes more meaningful, and I would blame my parish instead, for failing to catechize me properly.  Having been to both Catholic mass and Protestant service (both contemporary & liturgical), I firmly believe that all 3 are complementary.

@AndreasBlass You are discounting emotions as a primary part of religion whereas I am trying to point to the experience of a personal relationship.

@eques Certainly a personal relationship with the Living God should be felt if it is actual.  Can the Holy Spirit indwell someone unnoticed?

@MikeBorden Unnoticed is not the same thing as requiring a feeling. It may depend on what you mean by feeling. How it is commonly used would likely suggest a problematic state in that it associates the existence of an emotional response with the presence of God.

@eques If I put my hand too close to a flame I feel pain.  That pain might engender an emotional response, like fear, but the emotion is secondary whereas the felt pain is primary.  Experiencing salvation need not be and often is not an emotional response, primarily.  Going from spiritual death unto life should certainly be felt in a primary sense and this should generate emotions, such as newfound love of the Lord or neighbor.  Good discipleship discerns between the indwelling Spirit and the love generated, yet John 13:35 tells us the manifestation of love to others carries great weight.

@MikeBorden both pain and fear are bodily sensations. The Holy Spirit is well, a spirit, so any experience of Him will primarily be intellectual not sensitive.
